# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte (python)

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, decoding, bitcoin

I'm playing around, trying to pull a bitcoin block template using the getblocktemplate method.  I got a response but when I try to decode it from bytes I'm getting an error.  Check it out:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = "184.70.15.166" # choose a node from blockchain.info
PORT = 8333

s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(msg)
s.recv(1024)

x = random.randrange(320)
print(x)

data = json.dumps({'version': '2.0', 'id': 'x', 'method': 'getblocktemplate'}).encode('utf-8').strip()
s.send(data)
resp = s.recv(2048).decode('utf8')
print (resp)


# prints id number -
315

# prints response (in bytes) -
b'\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9verack\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\xf6\xe0\xe2\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9alert\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x1b\xf9\xaa\xea`\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xfe\xff\xff\x7f\x01\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00/URGENT: Alert key compromised, upgrade required\x00F0D\x02 e?\xeb\xd6A\x0fG\x0fk\xae\x11\xca\xd1\x9cHA;\xec\xb1\xac,\x17\xf9\x08\xfd\x0f\xd5;\xdc:\xbdR\x02 m\x0e\x9c\x96\xfe\x88\xd4\xa0\xf0\x1e\xd9\xde\xda\xe2\xb6\xf9\xe0\r\xa9L\xad\x0f\xec\xaa\xe6n\xcfh\x9b\xf7\x1bP\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9ping\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00-8\xc9\x03\xd7\xbc\x0f\xc9\xc2\x1d36'

# try to decode from bytes and get this error -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/myfolder/Desktop/bitcoin/bitcoin 2017/connection.py", line 66, in <module>
    print (resp.decode('utf8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

*What do you think?  I've been looking all over the web and can't find a fix that works.*

Comment: It seems that the data received by `s.recv` is not properly `utf-8` encoded, you may want to double check the server's api.

Comment: The getblocktemplate method is pretty standard w/ the json-rpc.  I wonder if I'm making a mistake with the data formats somewhere.  All I really want to do is pull the latest block template using he getblocktemplate method.  This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate solution is using `binascii` like this way:

For example, your data is:

```
a = b'\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9verack\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\xf6\xe0\xe2\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9alert\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x1b\xf9\xaa\xea`\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xfe\xff\xff\x7f\x01\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00/URGENT: Alert key compromised, upgrade required\x00F0D\x02 e?\xeb\xd6A\x0fG\x0fk\xae\x11\xca\xd1\x9cHA;\xec\xb1\xac,\x17\xf9\x08\xfd\x0f\xd5;\xdc:\xbdR\x02 m\x0e\x9c\x96\xfe\x88\xd4\xa0\xf0\x1e\xd9\xde\xda\xe2\xb6\xf9\xe0\r\xa9L\xad\x0f\xec\xaa\xe6n\xcfh\x9b\xf7\x1bP\xf9\xbe\xb4\xd9ping\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00-8\xc9\x03\xd7\xbc\x0f\xc9\xc2\x1d36'
```

You can do like this:

```
import binascii

# binascii.b2a_uu takes at most 45 bytes at once
# this why i'm splitting the data into chunks of 45 bytes at most
b = [a[k:k+45] for k in range(0, len(a), 45)]

# You can also use:
# binascii.b2a_uu(k).decode('UTF8')
final = "".join(binascii.b2a_uu(k).decode() for k in b)

print(final)
```

Output:

```
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7          @    M.,D#U[P/R<(=,S8
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't seem to quite be producing a comprehensible result.  I wonder if I'm making a mistake with the data formats somewhere.

Comment: If you have an idea about the decoded output data please share it. Otherwise, the bitcoin package built by Vitalik uses binascii as well.

Comment: I believe your answer is applicable.  I think I was making errors in outputting the data type.  The response needed to be a json object and I needed to handle the json load and a problem with a byte that couldn't be encoded to utf-8.  Learning as I go.

Answer (score 0):

I found a python rpc library for bitcoin called

```
python-bitcoinrpc
```

It solved my problem:

```
rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy('http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332'%('rpc_username','rpc_password'))

block_template = rpc_connection.getblocktemplate()

print(block_template)
```

Friendly API and works fantastically.